# Python - Selenium continue with same instances

Tags: python, selenium

I have a couple of problems. When I open new Selenium instance I want to continue with same instance but different requests.

For example: when I opened this url *https://example.com/login?token=1231232h31g23g123* and user logged in, after that I want to continue same instance or session different method.

My **main.py** codes:

```
import test2
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)
object = test2.ExampleClass()

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    slug = request.args.get("slug")
    data = object.welcome()

    return jsonify(data)


@app.route('/tutorials', methods=['GET'])
def tutorials():
    method = request.args.get("method")

    data = object.tutorials()

    return jsonify(data)

@app.route('/exit', methods=['GET'])
def exit():
    data = object.exit()

    return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 8001
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

and my Selenium Instance:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from flask import request
import time, logging
import shutil

class ExampleClass():
    stage = "welcome"
    token = ""

    def __init__(self):
        pathChrome = "/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver 2"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=pathChrome)
        self.driver.get("https://example.com/login")

    def welcome(self):
        identity = request.args.get("identity")
        password = request.args.get("password")
        self.token = request.args.get("token")

        driver = self.driver

        try:
            customer_field = driver.find_element_by_id("txtuserid")
            customer_field.clear()
            customer_field.send_keys(identity)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            logging.warning('txtuserid ID not found!')
            data = {"stage": "welcome", "status": 500,  "error": "You got error!"}

            return data

        try:
            password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("txtpass")
            password_field.clear()
            password_field.send_keys(password)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            logging.warning('txtpass ID not found!')
            data = {"stage": "welcome", "status": 500, "error": "You got error!"}

            return data

        data = {"stage": self.stage, "status": 200}

        driver.save_screenshot(filename="ss/" + str(self.token) + "/login" + ".png")

        return data
    def tutorials(self):
        page = request.args.get("page")
        driver = self.driver

        try:
            page_field = driver.find_element_by_id("pageId")
            page_field.clear()
            page_field.send_keys(page)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            logging.warning('pageId ID not found!')
            data = {"stage": "welcome", "status": 500, "error": "You got error!"}

            return data

        data = {"stage": self.stage, "status": 200}

        driver.save_screenshot(filename="ss/" + str(self.token) + "/tutorials" + ".png")

        return data

    def exit(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        exit_field = driver.find_element_by_id("btnExit")
        exit_field.click()

        data = {"stage": "exited", "status": 200}
        driver.save_screenshot(filename="ss/" + str(self.token) + "/exit" + ".png")

        shutil.rmtree("ss/" + self.token)
        driver.quit()

        return data
```

How can I continue with same instance till exit?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

so in my opinion you need define your

> self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=pathChrome)

in your main and every time you call the example class you pass the driver as parameter.